# How to record flash stream in php

Tags: php, flash, http, stream

I want to record flash stream using php. Do u guys know how to do that? I want script to record for example youtube file playing. I have VPS so it can use some software.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make script that simply downloads and saves the stream data in the file, but in that case, you must disable the 30 seconds limit for that file.
There can be made scripts that call themselves in infinite loop each 30 secs, but in that case you are in danger of missing some bytes from original stream.
But I don't recomend doing this using PHP. This language is rather designed to quickly process data for user and end (its "script").

Simplest script:

```
<?php
  $con = fsockopen("example.com",80):
  $file = fopen("data.flv","a");
  /*connection test skipped here*/
  fwrite("GET /stream1.flv HTTP/1.1\r\n",$con);
  fwrite("Connection: keep-alive\r\n",$con);
  fwrite("\r\n",$con);  //End of request data
  while(!eof($con)) {
    $bytes = fread($con,16);
    fwrite($file,$bytes);
  }
 ?>
```

Not recommended indeed.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, can you link any articles? I am better with C than php, but I thought that it would be easier, because I saw people doing things like that in PHP. I can disable time limit since i have VPS.

Comment: If you know C better, there is no reason to do this with PHP. PHP is far slower, you may have problems with asynchronous instances of the same script.
Fact that other people does this doesn't mean they're doing the right thing, mind that.
But for implementation of your idea, its enough to read [fsockopen](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) on php.net.